# Error: extensions must not contain stored properties in swift

Tags: generics, swift3

How can I add more properties to exists struct? As following I tried to add property `mass` into exist struct (that coming from third party I cannot control it) but get an error `extensions must not contain stored properties` or

```
struct Planet {
  let name: String
}

extension Planet {
  var mass: String? 
}

let planet = Planet(name: "Earth")
```

Comment: The error means what it says. You can only add computed properties. But you could wrap the instance in an umbrella struct.